# Prove that the real polynomial $P(x) = x^n + O(x^{n-1})$ approaches infinity for $x\to\pm\infty$ when $n$ is even

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem**

Take the real polynomial $$P(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +
 a_{n-2}x^{n-2} + \ldots + a_1x + a_0$$

where $n$ is even, and positive.

Prove that $f(x) \to \infty$ for $x\to\pm\infty$.

**My thoughts**

I know this. I've seen this. If I look at the functions $$x^2 + O(x), \\ x^4 + O(x^3), \\ x^6 + O(x^5), \\ \ldots$$ then I see that they eventually turn upwards, presumably because of something to do with their $n$th derivative?

Is there a specific theorem which states this? Or is the proof simple and short?

Comment: Consider the fraction $P(x)/x^n$ and its limit at $\pm\infty$.

Comment: @LutzL - That seems to be 1, since all other terms get an increasing power of $x$ in the denominator. Can I use this somehow?

Comment: Oh, so $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty} P(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}x^n$?

Comment: @Alec The conclusion "$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}P(x)=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} x^n$", even if one (both) limits are infinite, is correct in this case, however you have to prove it correctly, because you can't just use that "the limit of a quotient is a quotient of limits", because the limits are infinite and division does not make sense for infinite values.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro - Ah, yeah that was an oversight. Then I'm back to square one. Should I still use Lutz's advice regarding the quotient though, just in a different way?

Comment: @Alec Yes, Lutz's comment still applies: If $x$ is very large, then $P(x)/x^n$ will be close to $1$, say greater than $1/2$, so $P(x)$ will be greater than $x^n/2$, which is large.

Answer (score 1):

As
$$
\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\frac{P(x)}{x^n}=1
$$
we know that for some $R>0$
$$
|x|>R\implies \frac{P(x)}{x^n}>\frac12\implies P(x)>\frac12 x^n
$$
(the last step only valid for even $n$). From that follows the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the limit

$$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}\frac{P(x)}{{|x|}^{n-1}}=\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}|x|\pm a_{n-1} + g(x)$$

where $g(x)$ is a polynomial in $1/x$, and hence goes to $0$ as $x \to \pm\infty$. (And the $\pm$ signs in the limit and in the expression are not necessarily the same.)

In this form, it's pretty clear the limit is $+\infty$. Notice the assumption that $n$ is even is necessary to allow the simplification with the absolute value: when $n$ is even, for all $x$ we have that $x^n={(|x|)}^n$.